# .NET converting datetime to UTC given the timezone

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, utc

Using C#, I need to convert incoming datetime values into UTC. I know there is functionality in .NET for these conversions but all I have to identify the timezone is the standard timezone list

http://www.timegenie.com/timezones

What's the best way to do this in .NET? Will I need to create a mapping table to convert the timezones to the IDs in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones() (e.g. "Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)")
so that I can then use TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById()?

Thanks for any help

Comment: How will you know the incoming values had as a Timezone?

Comment: So your input is a `DateTime` and a UTC-offset? Then take a look at the [DateTimeOffset Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx). Otherwise, can you give an example of your input and the desired output?

Comment: How do you want to figure out whether AST is Arabic Standard Time (UTC+3) or Atlantic Standard Time (UTC-4)? The table is going to have several other ambiguities.

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653541/modifying-dates-in-asp-net-mvc-c-based-on-stored-time-zone/6826513#6826513 is not exactly what you have asked. But this will give good guidance on implementation.

Comment: @svick: You don't store the timezones in the database using ambiguous names like AST. You use their Id from a call to GetSystemTimeZones, which in those cases gives you 'Arabic Standard Time' and 'Atlantic Standard Time'.

Comment: @Bennor, yeah, but I was assuming the incoming dates are going to use the abbreviations.

Comment: Well, of course not.  He's getting a timestamp without any timezone indication and without a clue where it came from.  There wouldn't be any point in asking the question otherwise.  There still isn't.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've done it before by storing the timezone id in the database using a mapping table. i.e. A table containing the results of `TimeZone.GetSystemTimeZones()`

You don't actually need to use `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById()` though: you can do the conversion using one of the overloads of `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId()`. This method has some overloads which take DateTime values, and some that take DateTimeOffset values (which are preferable as they specify an unambiguous point in time).

e.g.

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.Now, "New Zealand Standard Time", "UTC")
```

The real benefit of using the system time zone id rather than an offset stored in the database is that daylight savings time is automatically handled for you by `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId`.

Answer (score 3):

[DateTime.ToUniversalTime Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Or

[DateTime.UtcNow Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx)

Comment: I think he's looking for parsing a string that has the date with Timezone information, where those method don't apply.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of information on MSDN about converting to different time zones.

- [DateTime (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx), specifically look at 'DateTime Operations'.
- [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx)

You probably want to use [ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382058.aspx) method (follow link for examples).